# TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am making a Hangman game in Python. In the game, one python file has a function that selects a random string from an array and stores it in a variable. That variable is then passed to a function in another file. That function stores a users guess as a string in a variable, then checks to see if that guess is in the word. However, whenever I type a letter and press enter, I get the error in the title of this question. Just so you know, I'm using Python 2.7. Here's the code for the function that takes a word:

```
import random

easyWords = ["car", "dog", "apple", "door", "drum"]

mediumWords = ["airplane", "monkey", "bananana", "window", "guitar"]

hardWords = ["motorcycle", "chuckwalla", "strawberry", "insulation", "didgeridoo"]

wordCount = []

#is called if the player chooses an easy game. 
#The words in the array it chooses are the shortest.
#the following three functions are the ones that
#choose the word randomly from their respective arrays.
def pickEasy():
    word = random.choice(easyWords)
    word = str(word)
    for i in range(1, len(word) + 1):
        wordCount.append("_")

#is called when the player chooses a medium game.
def pickMedium():
    word = random.choice(mediumWords)
    for i in range(1, len(word) + 1):
        wordCount.append("_")

#is called when the player chooses a hard game. 
def pickHard():
    word = random.choice(hardWords)
    for i in range(1, len(word) + 1):
        wordCount.append("_")
```

Now here is the code that takes the users guess and determines whether or not it is in the word chosen for the game (Pay no attention to the wordCount variable. Also, "words" is the name of the file with the code above.)):

```
from words import *
from art import *

def gamePlay(difficulty):
    if difficulty == 1:
        word = pickEasy()
        print start
        print wordCount
        getInput(word)

    elif difficulty == 2:
        word = pickMedium()
        print start
        print wordCount

    elif difficulty == 3:
        word = pickHard()
        print start
        print wordCount

def getInput(wordInput):
    wrong = 0
    guess = raw_input("Type a letter to see if it is in the word: \n").lower()

    if guess in wordInput:
        print "letter is in word"

    else:
        print "letter is not in word"
```

So far I have tried converting the "guess" variable in the gamePlay function to a string with str(), I've tried making it lowercase with .lower(), and I've done similar things in the words file. Here is the full error I get when I run this:

```
File "main.py", line 42, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 32, in main
    diff()
  File "main.py", line 17, in diff
    gamePlay(difficulty)
  File "/Users/Nathan/Desktop/Hangman/gameplay.py", line 9, in gamePlay
    getInput(word)
  File "/Users/Nathan/Desktop/Hangman/gameplay.py", line 25, in getInput
    if guess in wordInput:
```

The "main.py" you see is another python file I wrote. If you would like to see the others let me know. However, I feel the ones I've shown are the only important ones. Thank you for your time! Let me know if I left out any important details.

Comment: Amazing to me that this reached +22/-0 before I got here. It is a poor version of the question because a) there is no attempt to narrow down where in the code the problem occurs (thus it does not have a proper [mre]); b) the question is phrased to be about a reported symptom that has a huge variety of causes (so people who find it with a search engine are likely to have a completely different problem); c) the underlying problem, aside from being a typo when asked by more experienced programmers, is a clear duplicate asked about constantly by newcomers.

Comment: The underlying issue here is that OP seems to have expected the value `word` computed within `pickEasy` etc. to be available from the calling function `gamePlay`. Simply assigning `word = pickEasy()` etc. puts a variable with that name in scope, but does not actually give access to the caller's variable; it must be `return`ed properly, as explained in the linked duplicate (along with other strategies for communicating information from a called function back to its caller).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If a function does not return anything, e.g.:

```
def test():
    pass
```

it has an implicit return value of `None`.

Thus, as your `pick*` methods do not return anything, e.g.:

```
def pickEasy():
    word = random.choice(easyWords)
    word = str(word)
    for i in range(1, len(word) + 1):
        wordCount.append("_")
```

the lines that call them, e.g.:

```
word = pickEasy()
```

set `word` to `None`, so `wordInput` in `getInput` is `None`. This means that:

```
if guess in wordInput:
```

is the equivalent of:

```
if guess in None:
```

and `None` is an instance of `NoneType` which does not provide iterator/iteration functionality, so you get that type error.

The fix is to add the return type:

```
def pickEasy():
    word = random.choice(easyWords)
    word = str(word)
    for i in range(1, len(word) + 1):
        wordCount.append("_")
    return word
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved the problem. Just one more question, do you know how to tell WHERE a letter is in a string? So like if the word is "dog", and the player guesses "o", how could I tell that the letter they guessed is the 2nd character of the word? If don't know or don't want to answer that's fine. Thanks.

Comment: I am somehow unable to edit this answer, but instead of _return type_ I would write _return statement_. the return type is not (and does not have to be) defined.

Answer (score 0):

The python error says that `wordInput` is not an iterable -> it is of NoneType.

If you print `wordInput` before the offending line, you will see that `wordInput` is `None`.

Since `wordInput` is `None`, that means that the argument passed to the function is also `None`. In this case `word`. You assign the result of `pickEasy` to `word`.

The problem is that your `pickEasy` function does not return anything. In Python, a method that didn't return anything returns a NoneType.

I think you wanted to return a `word`, so this will suffice:

```
def pickEasy():
    word = random.choice(easyWords)
    word = str(word)
    for i in range(1, len(word) + 1):
        wordCount.append("_")
    return word
```