# Scrapy : TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: scrapy, nonetype

Whit scrapy, I receive this `NoneType` error when I launch my spider:

> if 'Jockey' in tab_arrivee_th: TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType'
>   is not iterable

The code works fine in the console test with a `list`, but not with the `response.css`. 
I think the problem comes from the `response_arrivee_th`, and I don't understand why, because the 'scrapy shell' gives me a list in return, and it's the same that I use in the test.

```
def parse(self, response):

    tab_arrivee_th = response.css('.arrivees th::text').extract()

  # list obtained whit the response.css from above in scrapy shell

  # tab_arrivee_th = ['Cl.', 'N°', 'Cheval', 'S/A', 'Œill.', 'Poids', 'Corde', 'Ecart', 'Jockey', 'Entraîneur', 'Tx', 'Récl.', 'Rapp. Ouv.']

    if 'Jockey' in tab_arrivee_th:
        col_jockey = tab_arrivee_th.index('Jockey') + 1
    elif 'Driver' in tab_arrivee_th:
        col_jockey = tab_arrivee_th.index('Driver') + 1
    else:
        col_jockey = 0


    jockey = partant.css('td:nth-child(' + str(col_jockey) + ') > a::text').extract()
```

> if 'Jockey' in tab_arrivee_th: TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType'
>   is not iterable

thx for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417403/typeerror-argument-of-type-nonetype-is-not-iterable)

Answer (score 2):

Solved : the 'response.css('.arrivees th::text').extract()' point to a list construct in js.
So I used scrapy-splash to have a 0.5 second delay.  And it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

the response for this  line `tab_arrivee_th = response.css('.arrivees th::text').extract()` is empty , check the response again.

Comment: I just checked and the response is a list : ['Cl.', 'N°', 'Cheval', 'S/A', 'Œill.', 'Poids', 'Corde', 'Ecart', 'Jockey', 'Entraîneur', 'Tx', 'Récl.', 'Rapp. Ouv.']